# Can JUnit make assertions about all Strings?

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking

Is there any way in JUnit (or any other testing framework) to make assertions about all possible inputs to a method?

Something like:

`assertTrue(myClass.myMethod(anyString))`

EDIT:
I realize that there are an infinite number of possible inputs but I guess I was wondering if there were some frameworks that could statically analyze a method and detect that in all possible cases a certain result would be reached. E.g. `public static boolean myMethod(String input) { return true; }` will always return true?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking; there are an infinite number of possible input strings; what exactly would you expect the testing framework to do here?

Comment: I realize that there are an infinite number of possible inputs but I guess I was wondering if there were some frameworks that could statically analyze a method and detect that in all possible cases a certain result would be reached. E.g.
    `public static boolean myMethod(String input) {
          return true;
    }`
will always return true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with JUnit. The only way I think you could do such a thing would be using [Formal Logic Verification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_verification)

Comment: @AlexWien I disagree. Yes, there are an infinite number of possible strings, but that's where the magic of else { ... } comes in. With an else block, I don't see why you couldn't do it

Comment: Yes for numbers, that should work, but I doubt the analysis (else..) understand the string operations, where. the code e.g picks out the middle 3 characters in case the first character is either a "A" or "B".

Comment: @AlexWien actually, that is exactly how formal logic checking works (AFAIK). You put a requirement on your method that states the string must not be null and must be at least 3 characters. That requirement then propagates to everywhere it's called. So everywhere the method is called, you have to prove that your String meets the requirements

Comment: Then in the myMethod method, you have a block if (str.length() < 3) { ... //do something else } else { //call myCharAt method with the formal logic }

Comment: The problem is that nobody puts a requirement on his input parameters. At least not formally described. But it would be better to discuss that with people who really have professional experience with FLV.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is practically an unlimited number of possible inputs.
Its your job to separate them into test cases with (expected) equivalent behaviour.
If such an artificial intelligence would exist, then it could also write the code to be tested.

There exist test case generators, that auto create test cases, but they are mostly useless. They produce a huge amount of test cases, and mainly only touch the code, instead of testing an expected result.

Such tools raise test coverage percentage, but in a very dubious way. (I would call that an illegal raise of test coverage: you should test, not touch!)

Such a tool is [CodePro](https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/download-codepro) from Google. Use CodePro->Test  Case generation (e.g within Eclipse)
On first you will be a bit suprised, it's not to bad to try it out. Then you will know the limits of auto test case generation.

Answer (score 0):

As said before, it's not possible. However, there's the approach of automated property based testing. This comes somehow as close as possible to your idea. Well, still far tough...

For instance, hava a look at [scalacheck](http://www.scalacheck.org/):

> ScalaCheck is a library written in Scala and used for automated
>   property-based testing of Scala or Java programs. ScalaCheck was
>   originally inspired by the Haskell library QuickCheck, but has also
>   ventured into its own.

Comment: I don't see that this comes close to his question, where an input string is the only argument, of the method to be tested.